# PHP - manually create date containing difference to greenwich

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, timezone

I've developed application which uses PayPal Adaptive Payments and for the Preapproval call I need to send startDate and endDate variables which should be in the following format:

> 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00

Now - since application is international, there are different time zones so I need to send each preapproval based on the timezone of the specific person - any idea how can I create the date in the above format from a standard mysql date (Y-m-d H:i:s) ?

I have a table of difference to greenwich values (i.e. +01:00, + 02:00), of which values are associated with the user - so I can pass it as parameter to the method which would create the date and time.

I think it's also worth mentioning that I've set up default timezone in the config using:

> date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question... But you can calculate each user's time by parsing those '+2:00' differences to hours and use it in such a way:

```
date('c', strtotime('+2 hours'));
```

If your server's time is UTC, this gives you current time for your '+2:00' user

For a custom date you do
`date('c', strtotime('+2 hours', strtotime($customDate)))`;

Comment: Yes - but what I need is the output in the following format: 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00

Comment: I specified this format (string 'c' tells date() to output in ISO 8601 date format). Try it yourself: echo date('c');